# Django solr_thumbnail cropped image are not loading

Tags: django, sorl-thumbnail

I want to generate thumbnails using solr_thumbnail but i am getting error .
I have followed the tutorial and generated the thumbnail and saved under cache folder. But now it is looking under `/home/vaibhav/TRAC/flipdiscounts/flipdiscounts/flipdiscountApp/images/cache/b2/f7/b2f7287e13292d73659a0fde830ef197.jpg/`

urls.py :

```
url(r'^images/(?P<path>.*)/$', 'django.views.static.serve',                                 # For store image
        {'document_root': MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': False}),
```

can someone help me ...

Answer (score 0):

try setting your MEDIA_ROOT root to `/home/vaibhav/TRAC/flipdiscounts/flipdiscounts/flipdiscountApp/images/`

and set your MEDIA_URL to `/images/`

and use this in your urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```